# Two pointer pattern to solve to reverse vowel problem in JS

Tags: javascript

I want to solve Reverse Vowel problem in Leetcode and decided to use Two pointers pattern to solve that problem. Here is the code.

```
var reverseVowels = function(s) {
    let arrS = s.split('')
    let vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u'];
    let start = 0;
    let end = arrS.length - 1;
    while(start < end) {
      if(!vowels.includes(arrS[start]) && !vowels.includes(arrS[end])) {
        start++;
        end--;
      } else if(vowels.includes(arrS[start]) && !vowels.includes(arrS[end])) {
        end--;
      } else if(!vowels.includes(arrS[start]) && vowels.includes(arrS[end])) {
        start++;
      } else if(vowels.includes(arrS[start]) && vowels.includes(arrS[end])) {
        let elementAtLo = arrS[start]
        arrS[start] = arrS[end];
        arrS[end] = elementAtLo;
        // let elementAtLo = arrS[start]
        //     arrS[start] = arrS[end]
        //     arrS[end] = elementAtLo
        start++;
        end--;
      } 
    }
    return arrS.join('')
};
```

As you can see the above code, if I find vowels in both pointers then I try to swap them. But the problem is if I use this code

```
arrS[start] = arrS[end];
arrS[end] = arrS[start];
```

then the overall function does not work. But if I use this

```
let elementAtLo = arrS[start]
        arrS[start] = arrS[end];
        arrS[end] = elementAtLo;
```

all works as expected. WHY? can someone kindly explain?

I cannot understand why my code works

Comment: After executing `arrS[start] = arrS[end];`, the value within `arrS[start]` has changed, so using it on the line below will give you that changed value. Your working code stores the _value_ in a variable before it's changed into a variable which does not change when you assign a value to `arrS[start]`.

Comment: @NickParsons aha exactly. Thank you))

Answer (score 3):

If you step through the code, the first example overwrites the value of the array so that its value cannot be retrieved.

```js
a=[0,1];
console.log(a[0]+', '+a[1]);
a[0]=a[1];
console.log(a[0]+', '+a[1]);
a[1]=a[0];
console.log(a[0]+', '+a[1]);
```

The second example uses a `tmp` temporary variable to store the value *before* it is overwritten so that it *can* be retrieved.

```js
a=[0,1];
console.log(a[0]+', '+a[1]);
tmp=a[1];
console.log(a[0]+', '+a[1]+', '+tmp);
a[1]=a[0];
console.log(a[0]+', '+a[1]+', '+tmp);
a[0]=tmp;
console.log(a[0]+', '+a[1]+', '+tmp);
```